# Fail to fetch javascript dynamic URL search input

Tags: javascript, vue.js, url, fetch, alpine.js

Why I'm having the Fail to Fetch error in the code while searching the dynamic url endpoint ? The syntacsic is correct I think.
https://codesandbox.io/s/onscroll-izfjoc?file=/index.html:1906-2125

```js
// html
<input
            type="text"
            class="input font--m1"
            placeholder="Search for the item"
            x-model="search"
            @keyup.enter="$store.products.getAllProducts(search)"
          />
          
// script js         
people: [],
getAllProducts(searchInput) {
    let searchUrl = searchInput;
    fetch(`http://test.mosvesna.ru/?search=${searchUrl}`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((res) => {
        let local = this;
          this.people = res;
      });
    }
```

Comment: Tested your codesandbox. Your fetch is blocked by CORS policy from the browser. Check if your enedpoint requires authentication or other headers. No noticeable error in your fetch script otherwise. If can see the response if you replace your fetch endpoint with some open API such as https://api.imgflip.com/get_memes

Comment: This is your error if you open browser console: `(index):214 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://codesandbox.io/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://test.mosvesna.ru/?search=321'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

Comment: Simply put, you can't fetch a http endpoint from https. If you have control, add `https` to your endpoint. Otherwise you need to use a proxy server.